# Power Bi Dax Calculated groups

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a Matrix visual that has the country at the rows and a couple of measures in the columns.

There is a net/gross switch that calculates the measures either in net or gross, which works fine.
Now i wanted to add some time calculations via calculated groups and have them as a filter to show each calculated item as selected in a slicer.

The created "current" values works fine with the net/gross switch.

```
Volume in m³    in m³   in m³   in m³   agg in to   agg in m³   C in m³
FR  318.826     174     524             276.686
FI  1.136.478   3.675   9.921   791.366
US  1.049.741   90  126 2.120   23.990  66.359      705.706
CR  1.601.513   3.742   1.020   9.215   5.590.855       1.347.199
```

If I switch to the YTD in the calculated group it is not using a filter, so all columns have the same values:

```
Volume in m³    in m³   in m³   in m³   agg in to   agg in m³   C in m³
FR  276.686 276.686 276.686 276.686 276.686 276.686 276.686
FI  705.706 705.706 705.706 705.706 705.706 705.706 705.706
US  791.366 791.366 791.366 791.366 791.366 791.366 791.366
CR  1.347.199   1.347.199   1.347.199   1.347.199   1.347.199   1.347.199   1.347.199
```

This is the calculated item for current:

```
Current = 
VAR SelectedType = SELECTEDVALUE(NetGross_Switch[Type])
VAR CurrentCountry = SELECTEDVALUE(DIM_PLANTS[LAND])
RETURN
SWITCH(TRUE(),
    SelectedType = "CO2 in Net",
    CALCULATE(
        SELECTEDMEASURE(),
        DIM_PLANTS[LAND] = CurrentCountry
    ),
    SelectedType = "CO2 in Gross",
    CALCULATE(
       SELECTEDMEASURE(), 
        DIM_PLANTS[LAND] = CurrentCountry
    ),
    BLANK()
)
```

This is the calculated item for the YTD:

```
YTD = 
VAR SelectedType = SELECTEDVALUE(NetGross_Switch[Type])
VAR CurrentCountry = SELECTEDVALUE(DIM_PLANTS[LAND])
RETURN
SWITCH(TRUE(),
    SelectedType = "CO2 in Net",
    CALCULATE(
        [_vertua_cat_vol_TOTAL], 
        DATESYTD(DIM_CALENDER[Date]), 
        DIM_PLANTS[LAND] = CurrentCountry
    ),
    SelectedType = "CO2 in Gross",
    CALCULATE(
        [_vertua_cat_vol_TOTAL_Gross], 
        DATESYTD(DIM_CALENDER[Date]), 
        DIM_PLANTS[LAND] = CurrentCountry
    ),
    BLANK()
)
```

So how to pass the selection of net/gross including the country filter to the measures?

The expectation is to have the matrix calculate the current and YTD values based on the selction of the net/gross switch.

Comment: Shouldn't your `YTD` item be using `SELECTEDMEASURE()` ?